# Invoking a copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have two pointers to class A declared globally

```
A* a;
A* b;

int main(){
     a = new A(...);           
}
```

How should I invoke a copy constructor to make b as copy BY VALUE of a. class A does not have any pointers as fields.

I do have a constructor declared, but I can remove it in order to not override the default one.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you put that [tag:linux] here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call the copy constructor with new:

```
b = new A(*a);
```

I gotta ask though... why not keep two static objects instead?

Comment: Got my vote. Because you answer the plain question, without unnecessary clutter.

Comment: @Peter, I really, really loled at your comment. So nowadays, when somebody asks something, we should just answer his question, even when he is going a completely wrong and stupid way? *That* is stupid.

Comment: @Griwes, Yes and no. I agree that we should ask guiding questions that make the OP ponder his design and explore better alternatives. But those questions sometimes get hidden in very long answers. It's almost a natural reaction to exclaim tl;dr.

Comment: @StoryTeller, no, it's just stupid and kills every way that such lost can learn *anything*. Go away from my sandbox to your one, where world is perfect and everybody only uses good techniques.

Comment: @Griwes, That's not the way public forums work, I'm afraid. You can react like an emotional snot nosed kid, if you want, but it doesn't change the fact that the often best way to teach is by dripping knowledge, rather than by pouring it on all at once in an overwhelming fashion.

Comment: @StoryTeller, "overwhelming"? Maybe for you, but definitely not for somebody that dreams about being able to write any sensible code in the future. And that sandbox part can be translated to this (since you clearly aren't smart enough to get it): **people like you are the source of the problem**.

Comment: @Griwes, Learn to debate like an adult, instead of like a petulant child. It's only cool when Linus does that.

Comment: Funny how you are still missing the point :D Anyway, I got better things to do than argue with someone completely wrong, peace out.

Comment: @StoryTeller Your code is actually pretty bad, now we're in 2013 and have C++11 widely available. And SO was meant to contain as much *generally* useful information, so it will benefit *as many people as possible*, not just the OP.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, I admit to not yet being aware of the better approaches C++11 offers. What is the better alternative it has? I'd love to see your input if you choose to answer yourself.

Comment: @StoryTeller Without having broader context than OP provided, it's really hard to choose the right solution here, and that's why I didn't write my answer. Certainly global pointers are a sign that something *may be* broken. **TL;DR** :  Some sort of scoped smart pointer would ensure proper cleanup.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, You made several valid points. The foremost is the lack of scope for the OP's question, which meant we can only ask the OP why doesn't he use other alternatives. But the point remains that the core question was how to call the copy constructor in the situation he presented. And personally, before proposing RAII I had to wonder why he was creating his objects on the heap to begin with.

Comment: @all: Sad to caused this kind of discussion. My point is, that a simple question should be answered simple and correct. I doesn't help sb. who asks sth. about pointers and arrays, when the answers tell him not to use them and instead smartpointers and template containers (I really dislike that, thats like "Don't learn to cook yourself. You can buy it!"). It's import to learn and understand the basics. On the other side, a continuative note or link is a good idea to improve.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things wrong with your code, that need to be fixed before answering the question.

1. The fact that those global pointers are global - having something global, at global namespace, is sign of bad design (if your teacher is advocating it - because it seems kinda like homework - then slap him in the face for doing so).
2. The fact that those global pointers are raw pointers - you either want to keep the ownership in their place and not pass the ownership around - then you'll use either `unique_ptr` or just plain object (unless the object is supposed to live longer than `main()`, but that's a weird case).

So, after correcting the code, it looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    A b(a);      
}
```

If you need to access those objects from other parts of the code, without explicitly passing them around, put them in sensibly named `namespace`:

```
// in header
namespace a_and_b // this is *wrong* name for it, of course
{
    extern A a;
    extern A b;
}

// in one of TUs - also possible to wrap this in namespace ... { ... }
A a_and_b::a;
A a_and_b::b(a_and_b::a);
```

Of course, if you are just asking for syntax, the answer would be:

```
A * b = new A(*a);
```

so just dereference the pointer to get `A` out of `A *`. But please, don't ever do this - even in freestanding environment you can easily implement own smart pointer to wrap this in sane way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't declare one you always get an implicit constructor, copy constructor and destructor that you can call like StoryTeller said;

```
b = new A(*a);
```

If you want to do anything in the copy constructor you need to write one, here's a bit about how you do that: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

Comment: Ah, hadn't seen that one. Thanks :)